# Fade transition slows down

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am getting a visible slowdown in the cocos2d scene replace transition between 2 scenes. It's is not very slow but is not 100% smooth. Interestingly it is smooth for standard resolution, but for retina there is a visible slowdown.

What could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any number of things. Consider what the engine renders during a transition:

- render first scene
- render other scene
- render transition effect

Normally only one scene is rendered. During a transition both scenes are rendered, plus the transition effect. That's most likely what's causing the slowdown.

Try to use a different transition effect (fade is particularly costly). Try reducing the complexity of either or both scenes during transition. If nothing helps, add an in-between "Loading" scene.